# Implementing Session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a piece of code which loads either french or english text and 2 link buttons that allow to switch between.

```
<%              
if publierFR = 0 Then
    if publierEN = 0 Then
        response.write("<p>Aucun texte n'est disponible.</p>")
    else
        response.write(texteEN)
    end if
else
    if publierEN = 1 or Session("lang") = "EN" then
%>          
        <asp:LinkButton OnClick="makeVisibleEN" ID="makeEN" runat="server" visible="false">Version Française</asp:LinkButton>           
        <asp:LinkButton OnClick ="makeVisibleFR" ID="makeFR" runat="server" visible="true">Version Anglaise</asp:LinkButton>
<%
        if makeEN.visible = true then
            response.write(texteEN)
        else
            response.write(texteFR)
        end if
    elseif publierEN = 0 or Session("lang") = "FR" then
        Response.write(texteFR)
    end if
end if
%>
```

What would be an efficient way of displaying the link buttons and text if both English and French exist and the session exists in either EN or FR.

I've thought of using panels to hide the buttons or text, but the main problem is having the page refresh to set the Session variable. `Response.redirect(URL)` to refresh the page i suppose and i can't find a better way to display the text other than to `Response.write` it since then i'd need a ton of labels.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .NET (and ASP.NET) native localization feature, and just change the culture of the thread that's executing the page. You can still store that culture in the Session if you want (or somewhere else: in a database, in a cookie, in the rendered page, in view state, etc.).

Here are some links on ASP.NET localization:

[Best practices for ASP.NET web application localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455132/best-practices-for-asp-net-web-application-localization)

[Asp.net multilingual web application - localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257221/asp-net-multilingual-web-application-localization)